# 2 questions.. first is i want the text to change in condition and the other is the button cant be click if meet the condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

[image] this is the sample code of what I'm trying to do.. on the condition "detailProduct.stock == 0". I want it to change the text if the condition is met. but the thing is only "Equipment Available" appears and "Out of Stock" never appears.. also my button. "Buy Now" I want it to be disabled if the stock = 0 like what I want in my first question. It's kind of hard to find and experiment with some syntax so ill ask here thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the value of `detailProduct.stock` is zero?

for button instead of using the `Link` element , try to use button itself and in the onClick event use `navigate` from [`react-router-dom`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

```
function TestElement(){
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [detailProduct, setDetailProduct] = useState({stock: 0})
    const handleClick=()=>{
        // handle your logic
        navigate('/cart') // react-router-dom v6
    
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick} disabled={detailProduct.stock === 0}>
                Buy Now
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: good day! actually for detailProduct.stock. its if else condition. if it reaches 0 then condition happens. that's what I want to happen, for my button, I think that's better syntax thanks! ill try it now

Comment: conditional rendering seems to be fine. just check what all are the values present in detailsProduct.

Comment: That's what I'm still doing. anyway, thanks mate for answering I appreciate it